# bash find user that originally launched script before su sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sudo, su

I have a bash shell script that must be run as root. If a user launches it they are asked for the root password and the script is rerun in a subshell. ./$0 &

Let's say a user named 'John' launches the script. After he provides the root password the script is rerun as root, but how can i tell who originally launched the script (John) from within the script itself? At the moment I am dumping a file with the original launcher which I can reference later but this is ugly.

Other options I considered are using the process list but again, there must be a more elgant solution.

GNU bash, version 4.2.45(2)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `$SUDO_USER` variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $SUDO_USER
```

output

```
[use1r@host]$ ./sudo-print.sh

[user1@host]$ sudo ./sudo-print.sh
user1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SUID to set the permissions the file uses to execute with.  This might keep your UID during execution if you are lucky, then you can scrape your UID a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

Check the Parent process id of the script ... owner of the parent process should be the user who executed the file.

To get the ppid probably you can use

```
echo $$
```

Or you can try to includle the code below in yoru bash script to return the original user

```
who am i
```

Comment: `$$` is the process ID of the current shell, which is not the owner of the script. You would need the process ID of the `sudo` command that runs the script.

Comment: As far as i remember for a subshell echo $$ would return process id of the parent shell... .. i don't have access to a linux terminal to verify this at this moment.. OR you can do a echo $PPID to get the parent process id

Comment: I just tried on an online terminal  #!/bin/bash ;
echo $$; ( echo $$) .. both returned the same value

Comment: `$$` always has the value of the parent shell in a subshell. However, `sudo` is not a subshell; it's a wholly separate process that runs the requested command in still another process.

Comment: The question says : I have a bash shell script that must be run as root. If a user launches it they are asked for the root password and the script is rerun in a subshell. ./$0 &
-- So if the script has echo $$, would it not return the process id of the shell where the command was entered? I get a shell when I log in .. and the owner of that shell process would be me.. in the case of this question.. this user happens to be 'John'.

Comment: All 3 gave the same output
#!/bin/bash
echo $$
( echo $$)
echo $$PPID